# How to get coverage result in HTML with gcovr, if we have only .gcov file but no .gcdo or .gcno files

Tags: code-coverage, keil, gcov, gcovr

When we get coverage result from Keil, we don't get any `.gcdo` `.gcno` files, but after using `COVERAGE gcov *`, we get .gcov files for each module.

There is option `-g` to use preprocessed `.gcov` file in gcovr, but I am unable to get any output.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's your project layout? Where are the .gcov files, and from which directory are you running gcovr? Which gcovr version are you using?

Comment: It looks like you are cross compiling for ARM, do you have Linux OS runtime available with you?, since the coverage data requires a filesystem to up and running for it to gather the results